# Bar Chart data points not getting values from Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm struggling with getting values from Firebase. I have a function which looks like this...

```
public func randomDataPoints(_ count: Int) -> [BarChart.DataPoint] {
        (0..<count).map({ _ -> BarChart.DataPoint in
          //  randomValue = CGFloat.random()
            print(counter)
            counter = counter + 1
           fireStoreDatabase.collection("day").whereField("email", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.email).order(by: "today").limit(to: 7).getDocuments { [self] (snapshot, error) in
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    if error != nil {
                            self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                                     print("in error")
                        } else{
                            if document.get("sleep") != nil && counter == snapshot!.count{
                            randomValue = document.get("sleep") as! CGFloat
                                print(randomValue)
                                thisDataPoint = BarChart.DataPoint(value: randomValue, complexValues: [(randomValue / 4, .red)]);
                                
                            }else{
                                thisDataPoint = BarChart.DataPoint(value: randomValue, complexValues: [(randomValue / 4, .red)]);
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                    
                    
                }
               
            }
           
            return thisDataPoint
            
        })
    }
```

The function generates a struct which is then used to plot data points on a bar graph. This is based upon this tutorial - https://blog.devgenius.io/swift-advanced-charts-from-scratch-c784971eacb8

I can see that the data is being returned from the database but it is not showing up on the bar chart.

If I take the piece of code...

```
 randomValue = 12.22
 thisDataPoint = BarChart.DataPoint(value: randomValue, complexValues: [(randomValue / 4, .red)]);
```

outside of my firebase query but within the function and run it - then this successfully shows up as values on my bar chart.

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a problem with async logic.
You are trying to return value ([BarChart.DataPoint]) synchronously, but firebase method works in async, so in the end you end up returning empty array.

Try something like this:

```
public func randomDataPoints(_ count: Int, completion: @escaping: ([BarChart.DataPoint] -> Void)) {
    var result: [BarChart.DataPoint] = []
    
    (0..<count).forEach({ _ in
        counter = counter + 1
        fireStoreDatabase.collection("day")
            .whereField("email", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.email).order(by: "today").limit(to: 7).getDocuments { [self] (snapshot, error) in
                
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                if error != nil {
                    self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                    print("in error")
                } else{
                    if document.get("sleep") != nil && counter == snapshot!.count{
                        randomValue = document.get("sleep") as! CGFloat
                        print(randomValue)
                        result.append(BarChart.DataPoint(value: randomValue, complexValues: [(randomValue / 4, .red)]))
                        
                    }else{
                        result.append(BarChart.DataPoint(value: randomValue, complexValues: [(randomValue / 4, .red)]))
                    }
                }
            }
                
                completion(result)
        }
    })
}
```

So, basically you want to do it all in async.
Create some result array, fill it inside your async firebase logic and then return.